# Tweak RayTracing Shader from Apple to get more Reflections

Tags: ios, gpu, metal, raytracing, compute-shader

I wonder, if it is possible within the metal code from Apples RayTracing demo* to get the objects rendered with more reflection (and reflective to each other). The RayTraced output resembles more a common Phong Shading instead of what one imagines by a RayTraced image.

*Original Sample Code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/metal_for_accelerating_ray_tracing

[image: Figure 1: RayTraced Metaballs]

I could not find any material specific configurations within the Original Objective-C code neither in any circulating Swift rendition.

Below is the original metal shader code, that is entirely consumed by the GPU.

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <simd/simd.h>

#import "ShaderTypes.h"

using namespace metal;

// Represents a three dimensional ray which will be intersected with the scene. The ray type
// is customized using properties of the MPSRayIntersector.
struct Ray {
    // Starting point
    packed_float3 origin;

    // Mask which will be bitwise AND-ed with per-triangle masks to filter out certain
    // intersections. This is used to make the light source visible to the camera but not
    // to shadow or secondary rays.
    uint mask;

    // Direction the ray is traveling
    packed_float3 direction;

    // Maximum intersection distance to accept. This is used to prevent shadow rays from
    // overshooting the light source when checking for visibility.
    float maxDistance;

    // The accumulated color along the ray's path so far
    float3 color;
};

// Represents an intersection between a ray and the scene, returned by the MPSRayIntersector.
// The intersection type is customized using properties of the MPSRayIntersector.
struct Intersection {
    // The distance from the ray origin to the intersection point. Negative if the ray did not
    // intersect the scene.
    float distance;

    // The index of the intersected primitive (triangle), if any. Undefined if the ray did not
    // intersect the scene.
    int primitiveIndex;

    // The barycentric coordinates of the intersection point, if any. Undefined if the ray did
    // not intersect the scene.
    float2 coordinates;
};

constant unsigned int primes[] = {
    2,   3,  5,  7,
    11, 13, 17, 19,
    23, 29, 31, 37,
    41, 43, 47, 53,
};

// Returns the i'th element of the Halton sequence using the d'th prime number as a
// base. The Halton sequence is a "low discrepency" sequence: the values appear
// random but are more evenly distributed then a purely random sequence. Each random
// value used to render the image should use a different independent dimension 'd',
// and each sample (frame) should use a different index 'i'. To decorrelate each
// pixel, a random offset can be applied to 'i'.
float halton(unsigned int i, unsigned int d) {
    unsigned int b = primes[d];

    float f = 1.0f;
    float invB = 1.0f / b;

    float r = 0;

    while (i > 0) {
        f = f * invB;
        r = r + f * (i % b);
        i = i / b;
    }

    return r;
}

// Generates rays starting from the camera origin and traveling towards the image plane aligned
// with the camera's coordinate system.
kernel void rayKernel(uint2 tid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
                      // Buffers bound on the CPU. Note that 'constant' should be used for small
                      // read-only data which will be reused across threads. 'device' should be
                      // used for writable data or data which will only be used by a single thread.
                      constant Uniforms & uniforms,
                      device Ray *rays,
                      texture2d<unsigned int> randomTex,
                      texture2d<float, access::write> dstTex)
{
    // Since we aligned the thread count to the threadgroup size, the thread index may be out of bounds
    // of the render target size.
    if (tid.x < uniforms.width && tid.y < uniforms.height) {
        // Compute linear ray index from 2D position
        unsigned int rayIdx = tid.y * uniforms.width + tid.x;

        // Ray we will produce
        device Ray & ray = rays[rayIdx];

        // Pixel coordinates for this thread
        float2 pixel = (float2)tid;

        // Apply a random offset to random number index to decorrelate pixels
        unsigned int offset = randomTex.read(tid).x;

        // Add a random offset to the pixel coordinates for antialiasing
        float2 r = float2(halton(offset + uniforms.frameIndex, 0),
                          halton(offset + uniforms.frameIndex, 1));

        pixel += r;

        // Map pixel coordinates to -1..1
        float2 uv = (float2)pixel / float2(uniforms.width, uniforms.height);
        uv = uv * 2.0f - 1.0f;

        constant Camera & camera = uniforms.camera;

        // Rays start at the camera position
        ray.origin = camera.position;

        // Map normalized pixel coordinates into camera's coordinate system
        ray.direction = normalize(uv.x * camera.right +
                                  uv.y * camera.up +
                                  camera.forward);
        // The camera emits primary rays
        ray.mask = RAY_MASK_PRIMARY;

        // Don't limit intersection distance
        ray.maxDistance = INFINITY;

        // Start with a fully white color. Each bounce will scale the color as light
        // is absorbed into surfaces.
        ray.color = float3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Clear the destination image to black
        dstTex.write(float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), tid);
    }
}

// Interpolates vertex attribute of an arbitrary type across the surface of a triangle
// given the barycentric coordinates and triangle index in an intersection struct
template<typename T>
inline T interpolateVertexAttribute(device T *attributes, Intersection intersection) {
    // Barycentric coordinates sum to one
    float3 uvw;
    uvw.xy = intersection.coordinates;
    uvw.z = 1.0f - uvw.x - uvw.y;

    unsigned int triangleIndex = intersection.primitiveIndex;

    // Lookup value for each vertex
    T T0 = attributes[triangleIndex * 3 + 0];
    T T1 = attributes[triangleIndex * 3 + 1];
    T T2 = attributes[triangleIndex * 3 + 2];

    // Compute sum of vertex attributes weighted by barycentric coordinates
    return uvw.x * T0 + uvw.y * T1 + uvw.z * T2;
}

// Uses the inversion method to map two uniformly random numbers to a three dimensional
// unit hemisphere where the probability of a given sample is proportional to the cosine
// of the angle between the sample direction and the "up" direction (0, 1, 0)
inline float3 sampleCosineWeightedHemisphere(float2 u) {
    float phi = 2.0f * M_PI_F * u.x;

    float cos_phi;
    float sin_phi = sincos(phi, cos_phi);

    float cos_theta = sqrt(u.y);
    float sin_theta = sqrt(1.0f - cos_theta * cos_theta);

    return float3(sin_theta * cos_phi, cos_theta, sin_theta * sin_phi);
}

// Maps two uniformly random numbers to the surface of a two-dimensional area light
// source and returns the direction to this point, the amount of light which travels
// between the intersection point and the sample point on the light source, as well
// as the distance between these two points.
inline void sampleAreaLight(constant AreaLight & light,
                            float2 u,
                            float3 position,
                            thread float3 & lightDirection,
                            thread float3 & lightColor,
                            thread float & lightDistance)
{
    // Map to -1..1
    u = u * 2.0f - 1.0f;

    // Transform into light's coordinate system
    float3 samplePosition = light.position +
                            light.right * u.x +
                            light.up * u.y;

    // Compute vector from sample point on light source to intersection point
    lightDirection = samplePosition - position;

    lightDistance = length(lightDirection);

    float inverseLightDistance = 1.0f / max(lightDistance, 1e-3f);

    // Normalize the light direction
    lightDirection *= inverseLightDistance;

    // Start with the light's color
    lightColor = light.color;

    // Light falls off with the inverse square of the distance to the intersection point
    lightColor *= (inverseLightDistance * inverseLightDistance);

    // Light also falls off with the cosine of angle between the intersection point and
    // the light source
    lightColor *= saturate(dot(-lightDirection, light.forward));
}

// Aligns a direction on the unit hemisphere such that the hemisphere's "up" direction
// (0, 1, 0) maps to the given surface normal direction
inline float3 alignHemisphereWithNormal(float3 sample, float3 normal) {
    // Set the "up" vector to the normal
    float3 up = normal;

    // Find an arbitrary direction perpendicular to the normal. This will become the
    // "right" vector.
    float3 right = normalize(cross(normal, float3(0.0072f, 1.0f, 0.0034f)));

    // Find a third vector perpendicular to the previous two. This will be the
    // "forward" vector.
    float3 forward = cross(right, up);

    // Map the direction on the unit hemisphere to the coordinate system aligned
    // with the normal.
    return sample.x * right + sample.y * up + sample.z * forward;
}

// Consumes ray/triangle intersection results to compute the shaded image
kernel void shadeKernel(uint2 tid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
                        constant Uniforms & uniforms,
                        device Ray *rays,
                        device Ray *shadowRays,
                        device Intersection *intersections,
                        device float3 *vertexColors,
                        device float3 *vertexNormals,
                        device uint *triangleMasks,
                        constant unsigned int & bounce,
                        texture2d<unsigned int> randomTex,
                        texture2d<float, access::write> dstTex)
{
    if (tid.x < uniforms.width && tid.y < uniforms.height) {
        unsigned int rayIdx = tid.y * uniforms.width + tid.x;
        device Ray & ray = rays[rayIdx];
        device Ray & shadowRay = shadowRays[rayIdx];
        device Intersection & intersection = intersections[rayIdx];

        float3 color = ray.color;

        // Intersection distance will be negative if ray missed or was disabled in a previous
        // iteration.
        if (ray.maxDistance >= 0.0f && intersection.distance >= 0.0f) {
            uint mask = triangleMasks[intersection.primitiveIndex];

            // The light source is included in the acceleration structure so we can see it in the
            // final image. However, we will compute and sample the lighting directly, so we mask
            // the light out for shadow and secondary rays.
            if (mask == TRIANGLE_MASK_GEOMETRY) {
                // Compute intersection point
                float3 intersectionPoint = ray.origin + ray.direction * intersection.distance;

                // Interpolate the vertex normal at the intersection point
                float3 surfaceNormal = interpolateVertexAttribute(vertexNormals, intersection);
                surfaceNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);

                unsigned int offset = randomTex.read(tid).x;

                // Look up two random numbers for this thread
                float2 r = float2(halton(offset + uniforms.frameIndex, 2 + bounce * 4 + 0),
                                  halton(offset + uniforms.frameIndex, 2 + bounce * 4 + 1));

                float3 lightDirection;
                float3 lightColor;
                float lightDistance;

                // Compute the direction to, color, and distance to a random point on the light
                // source
                sampleAreaLight(uniforms.light, r, intersectionPoint, lightDirection,
                                lightColor, lightDistance);

                // Scale the light color by the cosine of the angle between the light direction and
                // surface normal
                lightColor *= saturate(dot(surfaceNormal, lightDirection));

                // Interpolate the vertex color at the intersection point
                color *= interpolateVertexAttribute(vertexColors, intersection);

                // Compute the shadow ray. The shadow ray will check if the sample position on the
                // light source is actually visible from the intersection point we are shading.
                // If it is, the lighting contribution we just computed will be added to the
                // output image.

                // Add a small offset to the intersection point to avoid intersecting the same
                // triangle again.
                shadowRay.origin = intersectionPoint + surfaceNormal * 1e-3f;

                // Travel towards the light source
                shadowRay.direction = lightDirection;

                // Avoid intersecting the light source itself
                shadowRay.mask = RAY_MASK_SHADOW;

                // Don't overshoot the light source
                shadowRay.maxDistance = lightDistance - 1e-3f;

                // Multiply the color and lighting amount at the intersection point to get the final
                // color, and pass it along with the shadow ray so that it can be added to the
                // output image if needed.
                shadowRay.color = lightColor * color;

                // Next we choose a random direction to continue the path of the ray. This will
                // cause light to bounce between surfaces. Normally we would apply a fair bit of math
                // to compute the fraction of reflected by the current intersection point to the
                // previous point from the next point. However, by choosing a random direction with
                // probability proportional to the cosine (dot product) of the angle between the
                // sample direction and surface normal, the math entirely cancels out except for
                // multiplying by the interpolated vertex color. This sampling strategy also reduces
                // the amount of noise in the output image.
                r = float2(halton(offset + uniforms.frameIndex, 2 + bounce * 4 + 2),
                           halton(offset + uniforms.frameIndex, 2 + bounce * 4 + 3));

                float3 sampleDirection = sampleCosineWeightedHemisphere(r);
                sampleDirection = alignHemisphereWithNormal(sampleDirection, surfaceNormal);

                ray.origin = intersectionPoint + surfaceNormal * 1e-3f;
                ray.direction = sampleDirection;
                ray.color = color;
                ray.mask = RAY_MASK_SECONDARY;
            }
            else {
                // In this case, a ray coming from the camera hit the light source directly, so
                // we'll write the light color into the output image.
                dstTex.write(float4(uniforms.light.color, 1.0f), tid);

                // Terminate the ray's path
                ray.maxDistance = -1.0f;
                shadowRay.maxDistance = -1.0f;
            }
        }
        else {
            // The ray missed the scene, so terminate the ray's path
            ray.maxDistance = -1.0f;
            shadowRay.maxDistance = -1.0f;
        }
    }
}

// Checks if a shadow ray hit something on the way to the light source. If not, the point the
// shadow ray started from was not in shadow so it's color should be added to the output image.
kernel void shadowKernel(uint2 tid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
                         constant Uniforms & uniforms,
                         device Ray *shadowRays,
                         device float *intersections,
                         texture2d<float, access::read> srcTex,
                         texture2d<float, access::write> dstTex)
{
    if (tid.x < uniforms.width && tid.y < uniforms.height) {
        unsigned int rayIdx = tid.y * uniforms.width + tid.x;
        device Ray & shadowRay = shadowRays[rayIdx];

        // Use the MPSRayIntersection intersectionDataType property to return the
        // intersection distance for this kernel only. You don't need the other fields, so
        // you'll save memory bandwidth.
        float intersectionDistance = intersections[rayIdx];

        float3 color = srcTex.read(tid).xyz;

        // If the shadow ray wasn't disabled (max distance >= 0) and it didn't hit anything
        // on the way to the light source, add the color passed along with the shadow ray
        // to the output image.
        if (shadowRay.maxDistance >= 0.0f && intersectionDistance < 0.0f)
            color += shadowRay.color;

        // Write result to render target
        dstTex.write(float4(color, 1.0f), tid);
    }
}

// Accumulates the current frame's image with a running average of all previous frames to
// reduce noise over time.
kernel void accumulateKernel(uint2 tid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
                             constant Uniforms & uniforms,
                             texture2d<float> renderTex,
                             texture2d<float> prevTex,
                             texture2d<float, access::write> accumTex)
{
    if (tid.x < uniforms.width && tid.y < uniforms.height) {
        float3 color = renderTex.read(tid).xyz;

        // Compute the average of all frames including the current frame
        if (uniforms.frameIndex > 0) {
            float3 prevColor = prevTex.read(tid).xyz;
            prevColor *= uniforms.frameIndex;

            color += prevColor;
            color /= (uniforms.frameIndex + 1);
        }

        accumTex.write(float4(color, 1.0f), tid);
    }
}

// Screen filling quad in normalized device coordinates
constant float2 quadVertices[] = {
    float2(-1, -1),
    float2(-1,  1),
    float2( 1,  1),
    float2(-1, -1),
    float2( 1,  1),
    float2( 1, -1)
};

struct CopyVertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 uv;
};

// Simple vertex shader which passes through NDC quad positions
vertex CopyVertexOut copyVertex(unsigned short vid [[vertex_id]]) {
    float2 position = quadVertices[vid];

    CopyVertexOut out;

    out.position = float4(position, 0, 1);
    out.uv = position * 0.5f + 0.5f;

    return out;
}

// Simple fragment shader which copies a texture and applies a simple tonemapping function
fragment float4 copyFragment(CopyVertexOut in [[stage_in]],
                             texture2d<float> tex)
{
    constexpr sampler sam(min_filter::nearest, mag_filter::nearest, mip_filter::none);

    float3 color = tex.sample(sam, in.uv).xyz;

    // Apply a very simple tonemapping function to reduce the dynamic range of the
    // input image into a range which can be displayed on screen.
    color = color / (1.0f + color);

    return float4(color, 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. Reflections can be achieved like this:
Change this two lines of code:

```
// ORIGINAL
float3 sampleDirection = sampleCosineWeightedHemisphere(r);
sampleDirection = alignHemisphereWithNormal(sampleDirection, surfaceNormal);
```

Replace with:

```
// WITH REFLECTION
float3 sampleDirection = reflect(ray.direction, surfaceNormal);
```

Sample Output Render:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded this quite recently and the version I have doesn't have the HALTON random sequencer in it or the associated primes. Your replacement trick to produce reflections works nicely, though. How did you generate the blobs? I've populated my scene with dodecahedrons and other platonic solids.

Comment: I made an App, that creates Metaballs. Check out here, it's free: https://apps.apple.com/ch/app/ar-blob/id1490833957

Comment: Very nice app. Have you made any of the code available on Github by any chance?